# symfony don't fetch token in header

Tags: angular, symfony, jwt

I'm figuring a problem using jwt. in fact, I use angular to consume an API made with Symfony 3.4 and it generates a token but when I send it I set header with interceptor like this.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import {LoginService} from '../../services/authServices/login.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private auth: LoginService) {}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {

        if (req.url.indexOf('/admin') !== -1) {
            const authToken: string = `Bearer ${this.auth.getJwtToken()}`;

            if (authToken) {
                console.log('sending token to perform API fetch...');

                const authReq = req.clone({ setHeaders: { 'Authorization': authToken, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'} });
                console.log(authReq);

                return next.handle(
                    authReq
                );
            }

        }

        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

but Symfony returns a response 401 unauthorized when I tried to fetch resources from a protected route it seems like Symfony doesn't extract token as well

this is my lexik jwt config file I'm on Symfony 3.4

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    private_key_path:       '%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/private.pem' # required for token creation
    public_key_path:       '%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/private.pem'  # required for token verification
    pass_phrase:      "%user_pass%" # required for token creation, usage of an environment variable is recommended
    token_ttl:        3600
    user_identity_field: id  # key under which the user identity will be stored in the token payload
    clock_skew: 0

    # token encoding/decoding settings
    encoder:
        # token encoder/decoder service - default implementation based on the lcobucci/jwt library
        service:            lexik_jwt_authentication.encoder.lcobucci

        # encryption algorithm used by the encoder service
        signature_algorithm: RS256

    # token extraction settings
    token_extractors:
        # look for a token as Authorization Header
        authorization_header:
            enabled: true
            prefix:  Bearer
            name:    Authorization

        # check token in a cookie
        cookie:
            enabled: false
            name:    BEARER

        # check token in a query string parameter
        query_parameter:
            enabled: false
            name:    bearer
```

Comment: Have you tried doing this without Angular? For example, you could try to use Postman to see if Symfony returns a token and what happens when you set this token manually in the headers. This way, you can determine whether the problem is at Angular or Symfony.

Comment: I tried that and effectively is seems like the token generated by Symfony is invalid, to verify it i copied and paste the token on jwt official website and it was invalid so my question now is how to deal with that.

Comment: That's odd, are you using [LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle)? I recently made an API using that (although in Symfony 4.4) and it worked like a charm. If not, what are you using?

Comment: yes i'm using LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle with symfony 3.4

Comment: Could you post your LexikJWTAB config? You could also try setting it up from scratch, maybe something went wrong when generating the keys.

Comment: @Luctia my config file is too long to post here as a comment...Sorry to be late I'm a part-time worker

Comment: I suggest editing your post to include the information you told me, so that new users can also see it immediately. That way you can also include your config file.

Comment: I've created private.pem and public.pem again now my token is valid from jwt.io website but with postman, I receive this response when sending token in Authorization header with Bearer
`{
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Invalid JWT Token"
}`
and without Bearer, I have this response
`{
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Bad credentials"
}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

best way to user Interceptor for any cases is it will help

```
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
intercept (req:HttpRequest<any> , next : HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
        catchError(error=>{
            if(error instanceof HttpErrorResponse){
                const applicationError = error.headers.get('Application-Error');
                if(applicationError){
                    console.error(applicationError);
                    return throwError(applicationError);
                }
                // Model Error
                const serverError = error.error;
                let modelStateErrors='';
                if(serverError && typeof serverError ==='object'){
                    for(const key in serverError){
                        if(serverError[key]){
                            modelStateErrors += serverError[key] + '\n';
                        }
                    }                      
                }
                // un authorized errors
                if(error.status === 401){
                    return throwError (error.statusText);
                }
                return throwError (modelStateErrors || serverError || 'Server Error')
            }
        })
    )   
}
```

}

export const ErrorInterceptorProvider ={
    provide:HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass:ErrorInterceptor,
    multi:true}

Comment: thanks for that tip it is good for best practice but it doesn't solve my problem